# Volley-Mysql, Kotlin type mismatch error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

i am trying Android App to connect the Mysql through API call. I am following this article to create the app.

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/volley-with-kotlin/

But I have populate the mysql JSON result into 2 textView android objects. I am getting error while compile the String Request.

type mismatch: Expected string, Found: int, and another error which are attached here.

[StringRequest Function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NvWR.jpg)
[Type mismatch error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWL5t.png)

My code is here. I am new to this Kotlin, I couldn't figure out upto my level. where is the problem caused.. How do I resolve this?

//MainActivity.kt

```
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
    downtxtvalue = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.downtxt) as TextView
    uploadtxtvalue = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.uptxt) as TextView

    //findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGetspeed).setOnContextClickListener(getSpeed()){
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL_GET_ARTIST;
            Response.Listener<String> { s ->
        try {
            val obj = JSONObject(s)
            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                val array = obj.getJSONArray("internet")
                for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                    val objValue = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    objValue.getInt("download_value")
                    objValue.getInt("upload_value")
                }
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { volleyError -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
} }
```

Comment: Typo (`;` instead of `,`) between your `StringRequest()` arguments

Comment: I have tried using "," in StringRequest, but my android app suggests to use ";" instead ","  Otherwise it shows some syntex error.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?